# mediaplayer not working properly

Tags: android, forceclose

I have a problem trying to force close in my application.
Below is my code for playing sound when a button is clicked.
Can any body explain to me how to avoid the problem I am having?

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.Activity;

public class Click extends Activity
 {
  MediaPlayer mp1;

  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_click);

      mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound1);
      final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
      button1.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    }

   public void onClick(View v) 
     {
      switch(v.getId()) 
       {
        case R.id.button1:
        mp1.start();
        break;
       }
     } 
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem has to do with the fact that you did not implement `OnClickListener` and instead casted your `Click` class into an `OnClickListener`.

Modify your code as follows:

First the class declaration:

```
public class Click extends Activity implements OnClickListener
```

Then change

```
 button1.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
```

to just

```
button1.setOnClickListener(this);
```